# Question Regarding SolrFilter Query?

Tags: solr

I have a question that if Perform search in way that i have given "Solr/Lucene Statement" also "Filter Query" at solr admin page.. which one of both would be searched first.

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC they're independently evaluated, then intersected to get the final results. See the [docs on fq](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) and [FilterQueryGuidance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FilterQueryGuidance) for more details.